# npm install error "Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined"

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to run the “npm install” command on an admittedly old version of npm and have run into the following issue, even after running “npm  cache clean”, We are running version 1.3.6 because we are attempting to rebuild the existing software after a hardware failure. Any pointers would be appreciated.

```
npm WARN package.json ooi-ui@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-wavesurfer
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-wavesurfer
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-wavesurfer/-/videojs-wavesurfer-2.11.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-wavesurfer/-/videojs-wavesurfer-2.11.0.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/video.js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wavesurfer.js
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wavesurfer.js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/wavesurfer.js/-/wavesurfer.js-4.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/wavesurfer.js/-/wavesurfer.js-4.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/video.js
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/video.js/-/video.js-7.10.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/video.js/-/video.js-7.10.2.tgz
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/babel/runtime
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs/http-streaming/2.2.4
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs/xhr/2.5.1
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/global/4.3.2
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/keycode
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/safe-json-parse/4.0.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-font/3.2.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-vtt.js
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/keycode
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/keycode/-/keycode-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/safe-json-parse/4.0.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/safe-json-parse/-/safe-json-parse-4.0.0.tgz
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs/http-streaming/2.2.4
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/global/4.3.2
npm http 405 http://registry.npmjs.org/babel/runtime
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/global/-/global-4.3.2.tgz
npm ERR! TypeError: Cannot read property 'latest' of undefined
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:687:35)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:675:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:148:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-754.33.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/ooiui/ooi-ui
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! type non_object_property_load
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/keycode/-/keycode-2.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-vtt.js
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/safe-json-parse/-/safe-json-parse-4.0.0.tgz
npm ERR! Error: No dist in undefined package
npm ERR!     at next (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:746:26)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/cache.js:739:5
npm ERR!     at saved (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/get.js:148:7)
npm ERR!     at /usr/lib/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:133:7
npm ERR!     at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:108:15)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-754.33.1.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /var/ooiui/ooi-ui
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-vtt.js/-/videojs-vtt.js-0.15.2.tgz
npm http 404 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs/xhr/2.5.1
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/global/-/global-4.3.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-vtt.js/-/videojs-vtt.js-0.15.2.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-font/3.2.0
npm http GET http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-font/-/videojs-font-3.2.0.tgz
npm http 200 http://registry.npmjs.org/videojs-font/-/videojs-font-3.2.0.tgz
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/ooiui/ooi-ui/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

It seems pretty clear that the "404" error code means that npm is not finding the package from the registry. Is this a show stopper, or is there a way forward? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The TL;DR on this is update to `npm@2`.

npm 1.3.6 is 7 years old as of this writing. It is long out of support and the probability that it is incompatible with the current registry is very high.

In comparison, I notice you're running Node.js 0.10.48 which is "only" four years old. And while it too is long out of support, at least 0.10.48 is the most recent version in the 0.10 line. So that's good.

Node.js 0.10.48 shipped with npm 2.x, so somehow, you have an older version of npm than the version that came by default with the version of Node.js you're using. That's often a sign of multiple versions installed on the machine and PATH weirdness that can cause mysterious errors. If you're able to resolve that, it may fix your problem here.

The first dependency listed in your log above is videojs-wavesurfer 2.11.0. I tried installing that with Node.js 0.10.48 and npm 1.3.6. I got a certificate error, so I (temporarily) disabled SSL certificate verification. After doing that, I tried again and got an error similar to yours.

I updated to `npm@2` and then was able to install the package without a problem.